# How do I make my "Fn + Volume Up/Down" keys adjust my headphone channel in Ubuntu Jaunty?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, audio, ubuntu-9.04, fn-key

I always have my master channel muted, and I switched the volume applet to adjust the headphone channel. This way, sound never comes out of my speakers, but it's always on when I plug headphones in.

However, when I use my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys to adjust volume, they adjust the "master" channel, rather than the "headphone" channel. How do I change this behavior? If it makes a difference, I am using a Dell Inspiron 1200.

[Related question for solving this problem in Karmic](https://superuser.com/questions/51842)

Comment: Related question for solving this problem in Karmic: http://superuser.com/questions/51842

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specified by the ***System > Preferences > Sound*** menu option. Select the channel you want to control under the *Default Mixer Tracks* section.

[image: Sound Preferences]

Comment: This worked. To get any options another than "Master" in the list, I had to switch "Device" from the PulseAudio mixer to the Alsa Mixer. Does this mean that I am no longer using PulseAudio? Any side-effects I should know about?

Comment: I have an Apple keyboard, which also have similar keys, but i guess are having some different codes. How can I get the actual codes from my new keyboard, and how do I map those into the mixer ?

Comment: @jfmessier: Check answer from mas to this question http://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux