# Right Windows key on steelseries keyboard doesn't open Unity dash when pressed

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I recently purchased a steelseries keyboard. This keyboard has a steelseries key instead of a left Windows key, so I'm unable to open the Unity dash in Ubuntu 11.10 by pressing the left Windows key as I did on my previous keyboard. The keyboard does, however, have a right Windows key, but it doesn't seem to open the dash when pressed. I looked at the keyboard settings in Ubuntu, and it seems as if the right Windows key is being recognized as the Compose key, and not as the Super key.

Is there any way to get the right Windows key working like the left Windows key on my old keyboard did?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably work out which key is what with [xev](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) - lovely tool for working out keyboard maps on a unknown layout, then remap the keys with [xmodmap](https://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux), or a suitable configuration menu for unity (if you didn't want to create a custom keyboard map).

Comment: unfortunately, `xev` does not see any event when pressing this key

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without a new firmware (which I guess is very unlikely), mapping this key seems impossible.

Here is the response from SteelSeries support:

> I'm afraid this key is mapped in the firmware to be a modifier key for the f1-f6 functions - we don't have a modified version of the FW to change this I'm afraid so no driver or remapping software can touch it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use (GNOME) Tweaks to achieve your goal.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Launch Tweaks and go to "Keyboard & Mouse" section. Select "Right Super" for the Overview Shortcut option.