# Native windows10 rebind < and > to ( and ) and vise-versa, and [ and ] to { and }, \ to |, and ; to :

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

how on windows 10 rebind < and > to ( and ) and vise-versa, and [ and ] to { and }, \ to |, and ; to : ?

If not natively possible, what's most minimalist software to do it?

Comment: You can edit the registry directly to remap keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), it allows to do all sort wacky stuff with keyboard and among those is to edit key bindings.

EDIT1: The original question has only Windows tags but here are some for MacOS

[Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/)

[Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

Bonus Linux:

[SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux)

Comment: What about the mac?