# Mapping Specialized Computer Keys

Tags: linux, xorg, acer-aspire, keymap, xmodmap

I own an Acer Nitro computer, which comes with a "NitroSense" button which displays ACPI information on Windows once pressed. However, on Linux, pressing it doesn't do anything, and there is no equivalent application. Is there any way I can map or bind the key so it runs a script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap Keys in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux)

Comment: If it doesn't, can you perhaps indicate what you've looked into so far (by [edit]ing it into the question)? Even if your attempts didn't work out, that's still useful information for answerers.